# DiscordJS Backdoor Command

Tags: discord.js

I have had reports off my support server of my discord js bot of my bot being abused in multiple ways.
I want to have a way upon launch of my bot to see a list of servers as well as invite links to those servers. I do not know the id of server or anything.

### `The most I've managed to find out how to do is this`

````
    var server = client.guilds.get("idk the id part");
    console.log('I am in the following servers:');

    server.createInvite().then(invite =>
    console.log(server.name + "-" + invite.url)
);
});```
````

Comment: By those servers I mean all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ready` event (`client.on('ready', () => {}`), add the following lines:

```js
client.guilds.tap(guild => {
    console.log(`Name: ${guild.name} ID: ${guild.id}`);
})
```

This should output

```
Name: Test1 ID: 00000000000000
```

in the console for each server.

Also, considering that making a lot of invites might clog up your bot, and is generally more of a hindrance than help to server admins, you might consider making a `createinvite` command:

```js
const svID = args[0];
const guild = client.guilds.find(guild => guild.id === svID);
const channel = guild.channels.find(channel => channel.position === 1);
channel.createInvite()
    .then(invite => message.reply(invite.code));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either wait for the bot to emit it's `ready` event and loop through the guild collection:

```js
client.once('ready', () => {
  // client.guilds should be ready
});
```

or handle each guild individually:

```js
client.on('guildCreate', (guild) => {
  // The guild the bot just joined/connected to
  // Should also be emitted when the bot launches
});
```

Either should work, but my recommendation would be the second approach, as this will also allow you to track join events whilst the bot is running.